# TypeScript: typing functional mixins

Tags: typescript, object, functional-programming, mixins

I'm trying to write [functional mixins](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/functional-mixins-composing-software-ffb66d5e731c#:%7E:text=What%20is%20a%20Functional%20Mixin,and%20it%20will%20be%20extended.) in TypeScript. Here is what I have:

```
const flying = (o: object) => {
  let isFlying = false;

  return Object.assign({}, o, {
    fly() {
      isFlying = true;
      return this;
    },
    isFlying: () => isFlying,
    land() {
      isFlying = false;
      return this;
    }
  });
};

const quacking = (quack: string) => (o: object) =>
  Object.assign({}, o, {
    quack: () => quack
  });

const createDuck = (quack: string) => flying(quacking(quack)({}));
const duck = createDuck('Quack!');
duck.isFlying(); // TypeScript approves! ✅
duck.quack(); // TypeScript says there is no `quack` method!
```

My problem is, that TypeScript doesn't know that the duck can also quack. How can I help TypeScript understand what the previous mixins added?

(I think the error has to do with `o: object` ... Somehow it would need to infer the type of the argument, but make sure it is an object so `Object.assign` works. The other syntax could use the spread operator `{ ...o, ...{ /* ... flying or quacking ... */ } }`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TypeScript [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) to capture the type of your input parameter, instead of using `object`.

By using just plain `object`, TypeScript loses the information about the original input type and only is aware of the methods you've added. Using a generic will allow TypeScript to carry the original type forward and combine it properly with your augmentations.

```
const flying = <T extends {}>(o: T) => {
  let isFlying = false;

  return Object.assign({}, o, {
    fly() {
      isFlying = true;
      return this;
    },
    isFlying: () => isFlying,
    land() {
      isFlying = false;
      return this;
    }
  });
};

const quacking = <T extends {}>(quack: string) => (o: T) =>
  Object.assign({}, o, {
    quack: () => quack
  });

const createDuck = (quack: string) => flying(quacking(quack)({}));
const duck = createDuck('Quack!');
duck.isFlying(); // TypeScript approves! ✅
duck.quack(); // TypeScript approves! ✅
```

---

[Playground Link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=26&ssc=40&pln=2&pc=1#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAMwDYE8CWEDmcC8cA8AKnAKYAeMJEAJlHAN4C%20AfABRgBcchAlLsw2Bw4SEvDRQAYqgzY8CAIZIoJANzAhcAE5iArlohwA8gCMAViRAwAdAqhQ0mCKyYAaOGHf1Nw5ClZ83sLBcBLS6Fi4cDBaumo%20wTow%20oYwABYS6iGMrglhMlhcAfyhUgWYuSFICjTFQSGl4bJRisrxDdp6BtEZUFnBjJqMPOqM6qCQsHAAjroKIADWzXhEpBRUtAwsrLPzC1ywWrJ8OALsXLz8mqYWVrb2js5uHl4Ju4tFJwLvC0MjGuBoPAQDoFJQACK6RZRHZzD5wQ7HEp%20WSwvaon48FzDf6AqbUKELKIgkhgkiQxasADkAEU4QsAIRU-4ExbWfIRTABVRwAD0vO4KAADiQAMogtBC%20AKIVCrRgABuJCgDLggFByYCshbWH7cvkCwjCsUSqVwGVyxXK1VqoA)